# Python around 40 times slower than c++

Tags: c++, python, performance

I was implementing a rolling median solution and was not sure why my python implementation was around 40 times slower than c++ implementation.

Here are the complete implementations

C++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;

int tree[17][65536];

void insert(int x) { for (int i=0; i<17; i++) { tree[i][x]++; x/=2; } }
void erase(int x) { for (int i=0; i<17; i++) { tree[i][x]--; x/=2; } }
int kThElement(int k) {
    int a=0, b=16;
    while (b--) { a*=2; if (tree[b][a]<k) k-=tree[b][a++]; }
    return a;
}

long long sumOfMedians(int seed, int mul, int add, int N, int K) {
    long long result = 0;
    memset(tree, 0, sizeof(tree));
    vector<long long> temperatures;
    temperatures.push_back( seed );
    for (int i=1; i<N; i++)
      temperatures.push_back( ( temperatures.back()*mul+add ) % 65536 );
    for (int i=0; i<N; i++) {
      insert(temperatures[i]);
      if (i>=K) erase(temperatures[i-K]);
      if (i>=K-1) result += kThElement( (K+1)/2 );
    }
    return result;
}

// default input
// 47 5621 1 125000 1700
// output
// 4040137193

int main()
{   
  int seed,mul,add,N,K;
  cin >> seed >> mul >> add >> N >> K;
  cout << sumOfMedians(seed,mul,add,N,K)  << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Python

```
def insert(tree,levels,n):
        for i in xrange(levels):
                tree[i][n] += 1
                n /= 2
def delete(tree,levels,n):
        for i in xrange(levels):
                tree[i][n] -= 1
                n /= 2

def kthElem(tree,levels,k):
        a = 0
        for b in reversed(xrange(levels)):
                a *= 2
                if tree[b][a] < k:
                        k -= tree[b][a]
                        a += 1
        return a

def main():
        seed,mul,add,N,K = map(int,raw_input().split())
        levels = 17
        tree = [[0] * 65536 for _ in xrange(levels)]
        temps = [0] * N
        temps[0] = seed
        for i in xrange(1,N):
                temps[i] = (temps[i-1]*mul + add) % 65536
        result = 0
        for i in xrange(N):
                insert(tree,levels,temps[i])
                if (i >= K):
                        delete(tree,levels,temps[i-K])              
                if (i >= K-1):
                        result += kthElem(tree,levels,((K+1)/2))

        print result

# default input
# 47 5621 1 125000 1700
# output
# 4040137193
main()
```

On the above mentioned input (in the comments of the code) C++ code took around `0.06 seconds` while python took around `2.3 seconds`.

Can some one suggest the possible problems with my python code and how to improve to less than 10x performance hit?

I dont expect it to be anywhere near c++ implementation but to the order of 5-10x. I know I can optimize this by using libraries like numpy (and/or scipy). I am asking this question from the point of view of using python for solving programming challenges. These libraries are usually not allowed in these challenges. I am just asking if it is even possible to beat the timelimit for this algorithm in python.

If somebody is interested C++ code is borrowed from Floating median problem at http://community.topcoder.com/tc?module=Static&d1=match_editorials&d2=srm310

### [Edit]

For those who think using numpy arrays will improve the performance, it does not. On the otherhand just using numpy ndarray instead of list of list, performace further degraded to around 14 seconds which is more than 200x slowdown from c++.

Comment: What do you expect? Interpreted dynamic-typing Python to be as fast as compiled static-typing C++?

Comment: @BasicWolf No, but 40x slowdown is not expected.

Comment: @InbarRose Sorry. I updated the question. See the second last line.\

Comment: Try asking on [codereview.SE]

Comment: Looks like I will have to stop using python for competitive programming where the usual time limit for python is around 5 times that of C. and usually numpy (and/or scipy) are not allowed.

Comment: @Satvik Nope. We have to use better algorithms there :)

Comment: @Satvik Are you getting TLE?

Comment: @thefourtheye yes for python and no for c++. Time limit is 2sec for c++ and 6 sec for python. My c++ implementation passed all testcases in 0.29 sec while python implementation resulted in TLE.

Answer (score 4):

Pure Python code which is compute-bound and written procedurally is likely to be slow, as you have found.  If you want to make something in Python which runs quickly for tasks like this, you'll need to use some C (or C++, Fortran, or other) extensions, which are abundant.  For example, statistics and math people use NumPy and SciPy and related tools, which are easy to use from Python but which are actually implemented in compiled languages and have high performance (if used carefully).

If you want to try to squeeze a bit more performance out of pure Python, you can try using the "cProfile" module to analyze your code.  But it probably won't get anywhere near C++ speed unless you use smarter modules like NumPy or write your own extensions.

You might gain a small amount by refactoring this:

```
reversed(xrange(levels))
```

Especially if you are using Python 2.x, as this will create an actual list.  You can instead do something like this:

```
xrange(levels - 1, -1, -1)
```

Comment: I tried that it didn't improve much.

Comment: Did you profile your code?  That's far more important.

Comment: Haha.  Now go profile the code!

Comment: @thefourtheye Nothing interesting in the profiler output as most  of the time is spend in the loops.

Comment: @Satvik Check this profiled output http://ideone.com/gIkevX

Comment: @thefourtheye Yes. I also had the similar result. I went a step further to profile each line but nothing interesting.

Comment: @thefourtheye Looks like arrays are not the problem as using numpy arrays further degrade the performance. The bottleneck are the loops.

Comment: Yup. Most of the times its like 125000 * 17

Comment: @thefourtheye Performance went down to 200x from c++ while just using numpy ndarray instead of lists of lists. I am now out of options now.

Comment: @Satvik Even if it worked, TC wont accept it :P

Comment: @thefourtheye I am working on a different judge which had similar problem challenge.

Comment: @Satvik Which one has this problem? SPOJ, Timus?

Comment: @thefourtheye http://www.hackerearth.com/problem/algorithm/moving-stats/

Answer (score 2):

> Can some one suggest [...] how to improve to less than 10x performance hit?

1. Profile the code.
2. Look into using NumPy instead of native lists.
3. If that turns out to not be enough, look into using Cython for the critical part.